# Value not store in a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js function that use $.post to get data and store value in hidden field in the function it work fine but outside the function after calling function it won't work but if i use just alert('sometext'); before the alert the value of hidden field then it will store value and give correct output
code look like

```
function abc(){
    $.post('sch.php',{begin:'he'},function(data){
        $('#g').attr('value',data);
    });
}
//call a function
abc();
alert($('#g').attr('value'));
//won't alert stored value
```

Comment: You need to read up on how **AJAX** works. You'll have to move all of your code into the callback function.

Comment: is there any problem if i use

$.ajaxSetup({  
  async: false
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.post is asynchronous. data is not available while you trying to acceess it.You should use synchronous call or put all depended code inside callback method.Modified code:

```
function abc(callback ){
    $.post('sch.php',{begin:'he'},function(data){
        $('#g').attr('value',data); 
        callback ();
    });
}
//call a function
abc(function(){
alert($('#g').attr('value')); 
});
```

Comment: but outside abc(function(){
alert($('#g').attr('value')); 
});
it won't work i won't i can access globally// any way\\

Comment: @Arshpreet yes you can access it globally but make sure that callback of $.post is executed(data got set in hidden field).

Answer (score 0):

Use .val() to set a value.

```
$("#g").val(data);
```

Comment: you are alerting it before the ajax call completes. it's asynchronous. Do the alert inside the callback, not outside.

Comment: if i want to only store the value in that hidden field[using callback()] and want to use later then it will work[outside]

Comment: you can do that, but you by "later" you mean before the callback executes, you can't do that. An ajax call is like forking in other languages, you can't return from it. You can only use that value inside the callback. Maybe if you explain what you're trying to do...

Comment: i am storing session using php get retrive and store in that hidden field using ajax.post any other way u have!?//